# How to get values outside an interval pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, apply

I'm trying to get the values outside an interval in pandas dataframe, and I was trying to avoid iterating over the rows. is there any way to do that?

This is what I was trying, but it gives the error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
fence_low = 30
fence_high = 70
df_out = df[(df['A'] <= fence_low) or (df['A'] >= fence_high)]
df_out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the bitwise-OR operator rather than the `or` keyword:

```py
df[(df['A'] <= fence_low) | (df['A'] >= fence_high)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can negate [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```py
df_out = df[~df['A'].between(fence_low, fence_high, inclusive='neither')]
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use logical_and

```
df_out = df[np.logical_and(df.A<=fence_high , df.A>=fence_low)]
```